# How do I set the format VLC media player uses when recording?

Tags: vlc-media-player

How do I set the format [VLC media player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player) uses when recording?

I am getting giant AVIs which nobody can open (except VLC player itself).

Example MPC-HC output:

```
MPC AVI Source::Video 0

Media Type 0:
--------------------------
Video: RV32 1920x1080 11.999fps

AM_MEDIA_TYPE:
majortype: MEDIATYPE_Video {73646976-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}
subtype: Unknown GUID Name {32335652-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}
formattype: FORMAT_VideoInfo {05589F80-C356-11CE-BF01-00AA0055595A}
bFixedSizeSamples: 1
bTemporalCompression: 0
lSampleSize: 1572864
cbFormat: 88
```

Comment: The existing answer by @peanut_butter seems to be correct: To reduce the size use a highly compressing codec such as H264. One can only change the format between recordings, so you have to set it before starting to record; or stop recording in order to change the format for the next video. Please explain the reason for your bounty.

Comment: So, how to select format before recording? This is what I am seeking. Just like video tape recorder: press button and record what I am seeing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot change the format of the record button. The record button saves the file as VLC receives it, so AVI is saved as AVI and MPEG is saved as MPEG etc. http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=66641#p221956

Here's all about the record button http://wiki.robotz.com/index.php/Recording_Video_With_VLC.

Answer (score 11):

I am not sure what options you are using to record, or from what source, but it appears in your case that VLC is recording raw uncompressed video.

To record in different formats i.e. to encode the video and/or audio while recording, you can do the following (for VLC on Windows, but the solution should be cross platform)

1. Go to `Media -> Convert/Save` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.
   [image]
2. Select the source you want to use: File, Disc, Network Stream, Input Device etc.
3. Click on the `Convert/Save` button.
   [image]
4. Select a `Destination file`, and a `Profile` (the codec). The default profile should be fine.
   [image]
5. Click `Start` to start recording.

The resulting file should be suitably compressed (i.e. not gigantic) and open in any compatible player.

Comment: But is it possible to change format that appears after just pressing record button?

Comment: I.e. suppose VLC show something in some format. Does record button allow to capture exactly what is shown?

Comment: I do not know where the `Record` button is, but the steps above will capture whatever source you select, which you can also display while converting.

Comment: The data will be compressed using a [lossy algorithm](http://www.maximumcompression.com/lossless_vs_lossy.php) by default, but you can select a [lossless video codec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_codecs#Lossless_compression_2) that should give no loss of information

Comment: How to select another codec? I didn't understand it sorry.

Comment: Change the profile (Step 4). VLC lists the video codec first, then the audio codec, followed by the container. For example: `Video - H.264 + MP3(MP4)`. If you switch the video to Dirac, I believe that is lossless.

Comment: Ok sorry I meant is it possible to set codec while recording with red button? I would like to see the show and press red button from time to time. Is it possible?

Comment: I am not aware of a way change settings when using the record button.

Comment: To show the record button: View -> Advanced Controls

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The resulting file when played back doesn't have any video in it.

Comment: Same result as Matthew: the resulting file, although of plausible size, shows only the cone icon when played in VLC, and is rejected as "unknown codec" by every other player I tried.

Answer (score 1):

The procedure described by @peanut_butter is basically correct.

For **recording the screen**, see this article for detailed instructions:
*[Use VLC Media Player As Screen Capture & Recording Software](http://www.toptrix.net/2012/08/screen-capture-vlc-media-player.html)*.

You need to first choose the menu option *View* → *Advanced Controls*.

To record the screen:

- Choose menu *Media* → *Open capture device*
- Set *Capture mode* to *Desktop*
- On the *Play* button, click the down arrow and choose *Convert*
- Browse for a destination file (a new file, not existing)
- Press *Start* and recording will start
- To pause, press *Pause* in the *Advanced Controls*
- To continue recording, press *Play* in the *Advanced Controls*
- To stop recording, press Stop in the *Advanced Controls* and save the destination file.

Repeat this procedure for a new recording (with a new destination file).